# Apcahe cordova with visual studio

Tags: command

I am getting this error "**Command failed with exit code 1**" with visual apache cordova app when running with android emulator.
It is running with i phone emulator and nexus emulator.

Comment: You should post some code for us to be able to help you

Comment: I am using simple Jquery and html code It is running with ripple -Nexus Emulator but not working with android emulator.And giving this error (cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 
).